# Aesthetic Python console hangman

Tags: python, python-3.x, hangman

I tried to code a console hangman game that looks a lot like hangman often does on paper, with a scattering of incorrect guesses next to the drawing of the hangman.

```py
import functools
import math
import random
import sys

from string import ascii_lowercase


hangman_pictures = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========''']


def mistakes_and_hangman(mistakes: set[str], hangman_pictures: list[str], seed: int) -> str:
    r'''Returns an ascii art string showing the cloud of mistake guesses and the hangman picture

    :param mistakes: the set of letters to draw in the cloud of wrong guesses next to the hangman
    :param hangman_pictures: an ordered list of ascii-art strings representing the stages from empty gallows to game end
    :param seed: the seed for the mistakes cloud randomisation, each instance of the game should probably draw the same
        mistakes cloud for each turn
    '''
    try:
        hangman = hangman_pictures[len(mistakes)]
    except IndexError:
        hangman = hangman_pictures[-1]
    mistakes_cloud_height = len(hangman.splitlines())
    mistakes_cloud = make_mistakes_cloud(mistakes, seed, mistakes_cloud_height)
    lines = []
    for pair in zip(mistakes_cloud.splitlines(), hangman.splitlines()):
        line = ''.join(pair)
        lines.append(line)
    return '\n'.join(lines)


def make_mistakes_cloud(mistakes: set[str], seed: int, height: int) -> str:
    shape = mistakes_cloud_shape(height, seed)
    characters = [[letter if letter in mistakes else ' ' for letter in row] for row in shape]
    return '\n'.join([''.join(line) for line in characters])


def normal(x, mean, stddev):
    r'''Normal distribution probability function'''
    height = 1 / (stddev * math.sqrt(2 * math.pi))
    return height * math.exp(-0.5 * (x - mean) ** 2 / stddev ** 2)


def calc_stddev(row_number, widest_value, tightness):
    r'''Generate a stddev suitable for distributing the missed guesses of one row of the mistakes cloud.

    The topmost rows should have a much less concentrated spread of letters than the bottom rows, which
    should be tightly constrained around the means of those rows to look like the tail of a genie coming out
    of a lamp.

    :param tightness: between 0 and 1, a larger value means the stddev shrinks faster
    '''
    # return widest_value - row_number # the original linear method, where widest_value was the number of rows
    return widest_value * math.exp(-tightness * row_number)


def calc_mean(row_number, height, max_offset, funnel_factor, wavelength, seed):
    r'''Generate a mean according to a formula that will produce a sinuous smoke wisp shape.

    :param height: the total height in rows that the wisp will be
    :param max_offset: how horizontally far from 0 the widest point of inflection should be
    :param funnel_factor: a number 0 to 1, how much narrower the curves at the base of the wisp should be than the top
    :param wavelength: how much approximate distance (in terms of row_number) should there be between same-sided points of inflection
    :param seed: seed for the random number generator used to make the shape of the wisp different in different game instances
    :returns: the horizontal offset from the middle of the mistakes cloud that this row should be drawn at
    '''
    rand = random.Random()
    rand.seed(seed)
    funneling_factor = math.exp(math.log(funnel_factor)/height * row_number)
    translated_x = row_number + rand.randint(0, wavelength) # the offset should start according to RNG
    scaled_x = math.pi * 2 / wavelength * translated_x # scale to satisfy wavelength
    return max_offset * funneling_factor * math.sin(scaled_x)


@functools.cache
def mistakes_cloud_shape(height: int, seed: int) -> list[list[str]]:
    r'''Generate a 2D scattering of the alphabet in a grid according to a seeded random shape.

    At the moment, I'm going for a wisp-of-smoke/genie shape:
        #  # # #  #
      #   #
            # #  
         # #
      #
       #
    The method implemented is to align normal distributions horizontally with the middle of the smoke on each row
    according to some random sinusoid, and then placing the letters by weighted chance according to that distribution.
    '''
    rand = random.Random()
    rand.seed(seed)
    distribution = []
    width = height * 3
    for row_number in range(height):
        row = []
        distribution.append(row)
        mean = calc_mean(row_number, height, width / 2, 0.2, height, seed)
        stddev = calc_stddev(row_number, height, 0.5)
        for x in range(-width // 2 + 1, width // 2 + 1):
            row.append(normal(x, mean, stddev))
    grid = [[None for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)] # the output grid of letter positions
    letters = rand.sample(ascii_lowercase, len(ascii_lowercase))
    factor = 1 # keep increasing the distribution's probabilities so that all letters will be placed without player wait time
    factor_common_ratio = 1.01 # by this multiplicand each time
    while letters:
        for row_number, row in enumerate(distribution):
            if not letters:
                break
            for col_number, p in enumerate(row):
                if row_number > 0 and grid[row_number - 1][col_number]: # no vertical adjacency
                    continue
                elif row_number < height - 1 and grid[row_number + 1][col_number]:
                    continue
                elif col_number > 0 and grid[row_number][col_number - 1]: # no horizonal adjacency
                    continue
                elif col_number < width - 1 and grid[row_number][col_number + 1]:
                    continue
                elif grid[row_number][col_number]: # don't overwrite already-placed letters
                    continue
                elif rand.uniform(0, 1) < p * factor:
                    grid[row_number][col_number] = letters.pop()
                    if not letters:
                        break
        factor *= factor_common_ratio
    return grid


def masked_word(word: str, letters_guessed: set[str]) -> str:
    r'''Create the hangman hint based on the word and (correct) letters guessed so far.
    >>> masked_word('hello', {'e'})
    '_ e _ _ _'
    >>> masked_word('indubitable', {'i', 'l'})
    'i _ _ _ _ i _ _ _ l _'
    '''
    return ' '.join([letter if letter in letters_guessed else '_' for letter in word])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('common_words.txt', 'r') as f:
        common_words = f.read().splitlines()
    word = random.choice(common_words)

    art_seed = random.randint(0, sys.maxsize)
    hint_indent = len(hangman_pictures[0].splitlines())
    alphabet = set(ascii_lowercase)
    mistakes = set()
    correct = set()
    while len(mistakes) < len(hangman_pictures):
        print(mistakes_and_hangman(mistakes, hangman_pictures, art_seed))
        print(' ' * hint_indent, masked_word(word, correct))
        guess = input('Please guess a letter: ')
        while guess not in alphabet:
            guess = input("Please enter a single lowercase letter, like 'a', 'b', ... 'z': ")
        if guess in word:
            correct.add(guess)
            if len(set(word) - correct) == 0:
                break
        else:
            mistakes.add(guess)
        print() # blank line, separate the turns
    if len(mistakes) < len(hangman_pictures):
        print(mistakes_and_hangman(mistakes, hangman_pictures, art_seed))
        print(' ' * hint_indent, masked_word(word, correct))
        print('You beat the game!')
        print(f'You got it! The word was {word}.')
    else:
        print(mistakes_and_hangman(mistakes, hangman_pictures, art_seed))
        print('You hanged the man D:')
        print('You got as far as:', masked_word(word, correct))
        print('The word was:', word)
```

common_words.txt is just a sibling file containing a line-separated list of possible game words, e.g.:

```
instrument
palpable
jazz
famous
one
plenty
bet
bed
red
dynamite
dolomite
```

There are about 1000 words in the file I am using.

I would really appreciate feedback in the vein of software design: could I have structured the solution better? Are my data type choices suitable? Do the parts communicate appropriately?

Please let me know what you think of the documentation and comments too, are they sufficient and correct and in good style? This is a learning exercise for me, and I would like to develop practises that transfer well to larger serious projects.

As well as implementation alternatives for `mistakes_cloud_shape`, I couldn't think of a better solution than this PDF and maths-heavy one myself, but it's probably a lot more computationally expensive than it had to be. I've been using statements like

```
print(make_mistakes_cloud(set(ascii_lowercase), 10, 10))
```

to inspect its results.

Please critique the solution however else you may notice too, every time I've posted here before I've learnt some surprising and helpful details about Python, and about my own development.